# Javasсript для бегущей строки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста. Делаю сайт в нём есть бегущая строка HTML код. Как мне сделать чтоб при нажатии на бегущюю строку,разворачивалось окно с полным содержание строки?

```
<marquee
    bgcolor="#FFFAFA"
    direction="up"
    height="100"
    scrollamount="2"
    style="border: 2px solid #000000;
        text-align: center;
        color: #1C1C1C;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        line-height: 100%;
        text-shadow: #000000 0px 1px 1px;"
    width="100%">
</marquee>
```

Comment: покажите ваш код и верстку бегущей строки

Comment: <marquee bgcolor="#FFFAFA" direction="up" height="100" scrollamount="2" style="border: 2px solid #000000; text-align: center; color: #1C1C1C; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 100%; text-shadow: #000000 0px 1px 1px;" width="100%"></marquee>

Comment: Скажу честно я в этом деле новичок, у меня получилось только то же самое окно только выплывало оно само и текст с левого угла))))

Comment: Просто я не совсем поняла куда ставить.

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы написали, ниже дали ответ, попробуйте его или добавьте в вопрос пример, как все выглядеть должно

Comment: Я повторюсь,не совсем поняла как правильно вставить его в код или отдельно.Перепробовала по разному у меня не выходит. Не мог ли бы вы показать как правильно вставить его в код. Вот. Спасибо. PS: пойму если пошлёте.

Comment: _вставить его_, кого его? если `js` код, то через тег `<script>`

Answer (score 2):

Такое окно сойдет?

```js
document.querySelector('marquee').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  alert(target.textContent)
})
```

```html
<marquee bgcolor="#FFFAFA" direction="up" height="100" scrollamount="2" style="border: 2px solid #000000; text-align: center; color: #1C1C1C; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 100%; text-shadow: #000000 0px 1px 1px;" width="100%">Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста. Делаю сайт в нём есть бегущая строка HTML код. Как мне сделать чтоб при нажатии на бегущюю строку,разворачивалось окно с полным содержание строки?</marquee>
```